# Why doesn't my program finish when the Main method done?

Tags: java, serial-port, arduino, event-listener

i've recently gotten an `arduino` and started playing with it. I've written a `java` program to listen for input on the serial port from the `arduino` (or I've slightly modified some example code.

This is the code:

```
public class SerialListener implements SerialPortEventListener {
SerialPort serialPort;

/**
 * A BufferedReader which will be fed by a InputStreamReader 
 * converting the bytes into characters 
 * making the displayed results codepage independent
 */
private BufferedReader input;
/** The output stream to the port */
private OutputStream output;
/** Milliseconds to block while waiting for port open */
private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
/** Default bits per second for COM port. */
private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

public void initialize() {
    // the next line is for Raspberry Pi and 
    // gets us into the while loop and was suggested here was suggested http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=32186
    // System.setProperty("gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts", "/dev/ttyACM0");

    CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
    Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
        CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
        if (currPortId.getName().equals("COM3")) {
            portId = currPortId;
            break;
        }
    }


    try {
        // open serial port, and use class name for the appName.
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
                TIME_OUT);

        // set port parameters
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

        // open the streams
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
        output = serialPort.getOutputStream();

        // add event listeners
        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
        serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
}

/**
 * This should be called when you stop using the port.
 * This will prevent port locking on platforms like Linux.
 */
public synchronized void close() {
    if (serialPort != null) {
        serialPort.removeEventListener();
        serialPort.close();
    }
}

/**
 * Handle an event on the serial port. Read the data and print it.
 */
public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
        try {
            String inputLine=input.readLine();
            System.out.println(inputLine);
            FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter("C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\temp.txt");
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter (fWriter);
            writer.write(inputLine);
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SerialListener tempListener = new SerialListener();
    tempListener.initialize();

}
}
```

I understand that the `SerialListener` class implements the method to handle `SerialPort Events` and that I in the initiate method are setting the object of the `SerialListner` class to listen for events.

What I don't understand is why this program don't immediately quit, since it does nothing in the main method after running the initialize method.

Are event listeners run on different threads or why does this work? (Because this works as I want it to)

The code I've basically copied can be found here:
http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Java
under "Java Sample Code" But as you can see I don't start a class which keeps it alive for 1000 seconds as they say in the example

Comment: Are you sure `tempListener.initialize();` is returning?

Comment: Yeah, since the listeners do get set? and it does listen to the events

Comment: I'm guessing the SerialPort starts up a non-daemon thread to do its work, since it reports back to a listener, and that thread is still running which keeps the JVM from shutting down. You should check its docs to see if there's something you need to do to shut it down cleanly (or a way to have it make its thread a daemon thread (background thread)).

Comment: Do you know how I make it a daemon thread? My thinking is to have this program run all the time on my computer and update my website with the current temperature outside my window

Answer (score 0):

What if you add the following at the end of you main method:

```
tempListener.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/javacomm/reference/api/javax/comm/SerialPort.html#addEventListener(javax.comm.SerialPortEventListener)) on `SerialPort.addEventListener()`:

> All the events received by this listener are generated by one dedicated thread that belongs to the SerialPort object.

So I guess the `SerialPort` has a thread running. Try calling `tempListener.close();` afterwards.

Comment: Thank you! How did you find the docs? and why is it that the SerialPort is a GNU library the docs are on the oracle page?

Comment: Because I did a quick google and got the docs for `javax.comm.SerialPort` instead? :P

Comment: So it is not the same? :P How do I use "that" serialport instead? (I've just followed the tutorial or Arduinos webpage)

Comment: I'm assuming `gnu.io.SerialPort` does a similar thing, since event handlers spawning separate threads makes sense (how else would it actually run the event handler?).